# OpenTok JS connection timeout issue while loading resources

Tags: javascript, opentok, tokbox

I'm using opentok client JS api, to set up a video conferencing app. Intermittently, the js and css resources from open tok servers fail to load.

These are the errors I'm seeing on developer console in Chrome Browser.  I have a good internet connection and it's not always. I think, these resources are being loaded from opentok.min.js. I have that file as local resource. Is there way to avoid such issues ?

http://static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.2.9.6/js/dynamic_config.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

http://static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.2.9.6/css/ot.min.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Once this happens, I'll not be able to see other party's video. Any help is appreciated ? What is the best practice to avoid this issue in a production environment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are running into some intermittent network connectivity issues. You mentioned:

> I have a good internet connection and it's not always

Which I understood to mean that you don't always get the errors.

This is what I believe is happening: because you have the `opentok.min.js` file downloaded locally, you are able to obtain this resource every single time; even when your network connectivity is down. However, this file also obtains other files that are hosted on TokBox servers dynamically. Namely, the `dynamic_config.min.js` and `ot.min.css` files. When those resources are requested and are not able to be obtained, you get the network timeout error.

As for best practices, TokBox recommends that you not locally download the `OpenTok.min.js` file, but instead use:

```
<script src='//static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.2/js/opentok.min.js'></script>
```

This won't solve the problem if it is in fact due to network issues, but it will fail fast for your debugging purposes.

Comment: "I have a good internet connection and it's not always" - I meant, I do have good internet connection and opentok works most of the time. But, sometimes it's not able to load the opentok resources. At that moment, I cross checked with other websites, and I was able to access other sites. So, wondering what might be the issue. I'm using free trial account. Are there different urls, for paid / subscribed accounts ?

Comment: No, the trial account provides full access to platform using the exact same resources. I can't immediately think of a reason for you to get this timeout message other than network issues.